Prohibiting the display of attributes of other users in FREEIPA
How can I restrict the viewing of information about other users for a specific user/group on the FREEIPA server? (via user-find or web interface)

Update:
You can set your own attributes to read only by:
Permission - System:Read standart user attributes - "self"
But in this case, some hosts with authentication stop working. I would like to understand how to differentiate the visibility of attributes for a group of users and other system resources.
